# jQuery Use URL hash to select option forms

Tags: jquery, forms, hash

I'm trying to use URL hash to select option and when the option changes, url hash changes. I got two scripts, they work independently, but not together. Is there a solution? currently it works with url.com/#Apple, which selects Apple. But when I change selection to Orange, the URL doesn't change to url.com/#Orange  Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q33zevup/1/

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange B</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>

 <script>
    $('#myselect').change(function(){
        var url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
    });
    </script> 
    <script>
    jQuery.noConflict();
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

    window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

    function fn() {
        document.getElementById('myselect').value = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @JackalopeZero http://jsfiddle.net/q33zevup/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me after changing the "myselect" in the javascript to match the "mySelect" (case difference) in the html. http://jsfiddle.net/q33zevup/3/

```
$(function(){
    $('#mySelect').change(function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
        console.log('select Changed');
    });
});
window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    $('#mySelect').val(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
}
```

Comment: currently it works with url.com/#Apple, which selects Apple. But when I change selection to Orange, the URL doesn't change to url.com/#Orange

Comment: Strange... it works fine for me. Wait.... Do you have your $('#mySelect').change function inside a $(function(){ ... }); wrapper? See my Edited code above.

Comment: Thanks it does work, but my page has a script conflict. I tried to put  jQuery.noConflict(); before function fn(), but I can't seem to get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/q33zevup/4/

Comment: That's an improper use of jQuery.noConflict(); you can either replace all the '$' with 'jQuery' or you can do: $j = jQuery.noConflict(); Then use '$j' instead of '$' in the code.